# Is there a way to do a ranged for loop in Actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, for-loop, range

Is there a range operator in ActionScript 3.0 that I can use to specify the number of times a for loop loops?

Besides the obvious way of using a loop index, of course.

Comment: I was just dealing with this the other day. No range sadly :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. (more characters to meet the minimum number required)

Comment: Ha, yeah the minimum character thing is a pain. Thanks.